# alert() is alerting more than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(function(){
       $("button").click(function(){
         $("div").load("AJAX_page.php");
       });
       $("span").on("click",function(){alert("This function is necessary")})   
     });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <button>LOAD</button>
   <span>Click on me After clicking on button</span>
   <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my AJAX_page.php

```
<body>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("span").on("click", hello);

    function hello() {
        alert("hi");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

Now my problem is

1. First when you click on button and then if you will click on span it
   will alert **hello** and **this function is necessary**
2. Again if you will click on button then it will alert **hello** and
   **this function is necessary** 2 times
3. Again if you will click on button then it will alert **hello** and
   **this function is necessary** 3 times and so on

Now i want it to alert only **this function is necessary** and  **hello** only one time no matter how many times the button is clicked?

Comment: That's because on each click on the button you are loading the the other page which executes `$("span").on("click",hello);`. So on every click you bind a new click event handler.

Comment: That's the point i know this but can't deal with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you unbind the previously bound event handler:

```
$("span").off('click', hello).on('click', hello);
```

**This won't work in your case** since at each evaluation of the JavaScript code, a new `hello` function is created, which is a different instance than the one your previously bound.

But all is not lost: You can make use of [namespaced events *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events), to only unbind specific handlers:

```
$("span").off('click.foo').on('click.foo', hello)
```

Or load the other code only once if possible.

Comment: Some random namespace... choose any word.

Comment: @Felix Just for me: I don't understand how the function hello() is just called once. I my eyes you remove the eventhandle and in the next step you added it again.

Comment: @reporter: In the original code, whenever the button is clicked, `hello` is bound to the `span` element. That means, after clicking the button five times, you have bound the function five times as event handler to the element. But if you *remove* the previously bound handler before you bind it anew, you make sure that at any time only one event handler is bound.

Comment: @Felix Thanks for explaination. So I could see my mistakes in understanding of the OP's question.

Comment: @FelixKling your code is not working and the script is working as before because hello function has also 5 copies in my case.Please try it on your computer

Comment: @Random What will happen if you wrap your js code -in index.php- into $(document).ready() ?

Comment: may you tell me how to load it once

Comment: @reporter it is not possible because i have to use AJAX

Comment: @Random: I assume you did not try namespaced events? It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4Y5Qp/. The first way I suggested does actually not work, will update...

Answer (score 0):

The script in the AJAX_page.php file is being run every time you click the button, meaning it's attaching a new event handler every time you click the button.

Presumably the code you give here is an abstraction of what you're really trying to do, so I don't know if you really need the button to run the script in AJAX_page.php every time it is clicked or just once. If you only need it once, then attach the click handler on the button with `$("button").one("click", function() { ... })`; this will unbind the handler after you press the button the first time, so that the span gets its onclick event the first time you press the button but nothing happens on subsequent times you press the button.

If the AJAX_page.php file is going to be returning different things from the server at different times and the alert on the span should be updated when the button is pressed, you'll need to unbind the previously attached handler as the previous answer suggests. (The 'foo' can be any string you want that identifies this click event and not some other click event on the same element; 'hello' would probably be more mnemonic for this example.)